# Distributed Transaction Management

Tags: microservices

How to maintain the Transactions Consistency  in a microservices application.
Lets say you have one transactions which includes call to an api service before commiting anything to the db. Now if the Db gets failed then we need to send some compensation transaction to that Api Microservice. But if that point of time current micsroservice gets down then we will not be able to send the compensation transaction to that api microservice.
How to deal these types of scenarioes.

Distributed Transaction Management